# run javascript in background service on android phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Am working on app which i recently implemented a background service with help from the following: https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService/

Everything works fine and the service runs in the background when the phone is restarted. 
But in the background service which executes a Java method Every 5mins 'DoWork' Line 20 https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService/blob/master/2.2.0/MyService.java

```
  package com.yournamespace.yourappname;
```

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

import com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.BackgroundService;

public class MyService extends BackgroundService {

```
private final static String TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();

private String mHelloTo = "World";

@Override
protected JSONObject doWork() {
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

    try {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); 
        String now = df.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())); 

        String msg = "Hello " + this.mHelloTo + " - its currently " + now;
        result.put("Message", msg);

        Log.d(TAG, msg);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }

    return result;  
}

@Override
protected JSONObject getConfig() {
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

    try {
        result.put("HelloTo", this.mHelloTo);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }

    return result;
}

@Override
protected void setConfig(JSONObject config) {
    try {
        if (config.has("HelloTo"))
            this.mHelloTo = config.getString("HelloTo");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }

}     

@Override
protected JSONObject initialiseLatestResult() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onTimerEnabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
protected void onTimerDisabled() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

I would like to call a JavaScript function also from that method.
The Javascript Function does the following:
- Gets all the device contacts
- Get the device GeoLocation
- Get the device IMEI and phonenumber

and post to an external server.
I would like to know if that is possible i.e calling the javascript function from Java.
Note: I do not know much about Java so detailed explanation will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: why do you want to steal contacts and snoop user location every five mins?

Comment: I am in an app competition at school and i want the app to be able to backup the users contact. Also in case the phone gets stolen, users can see real time map location of where their mobile phone is via google maps.

Comment: Lots of students loose their phones in school so it would be nice if they could at least know where it is.